# Error while exporting FBX files (Character and Armature)

Tags: rigging, armature

just got this problem after i put armature to my character and i cannot export it. Before this i have not problem while exporting the character in fbx files (without armature) but now i cannot export out my character mesh. i already remake my uv, clean up the mesh but still i cannot export it out. [image]

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question if you can.  (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: it looks like you are using a custom .fbx exporter. What Blender version are you using. Can you share a capture of your rig in 3d viewport, the outliner? Do you have drivers setup? Are you using the uv space 0,0? or any other special uv space in your coordinates? Does this .fbx have motion?

Comment: Thank you for commenting on this post, i already solved the problem. In my UV map, i dont how but my uv map have pin which i knew use it before and suddenly appear on uv map. After i clean it up all the pin and unwrap back, everthing was fine and im able to export it.